# Why does aiohttp.ClientSession() object .get() Method Return Results In Order Even Though It Is Asynchronous?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I found myself wondering if aiohttp.ClientSession() would return results sequentially because it was supposed to call a server many times, and then wait for all of the replies to arrive. I was expecting the results to be returned in a non-sequential order.

Additionally, the rate of replies varied, but strangely enough, they still remained in sequence.

I ran the below code multiple times:

```
async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        res_dict={}
        for number in range(1, 100):
            pokemon_url = f'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{number}'
            async with session.get(pokemon_url) as resp:
                pokemon = await resp.json()
                res_dict[number]=pokemon['id']
                print(pokemon['id'])
        for i in res_dict:
            print(i, '=',res_dict[i])

asyncio.run(main())
```

And every time I ran it, I received the results in a perfectly ordered reply:

`1 2 3 . . . 98 99`

And they were also correctly paired up with each of their dict Keys as well:

`1=1 2=2 3=3 . . . 98=98 99=99`

Would I be correct to assume that like asyncio.gather(), an aiohttp.ClientSession object's .get() method will make queries and receive them asynchronously, only listing them if they arrive in order? I also noticed that the rate of replies being received varied, and that could be a possible explanation as to why this is happening.

Comment: are you questioning why the two for loops run sequentially (one after the other) or about the http request ?    (you are correct on the HTTP request part).

Comment: @D.L, ah, yes, I was only asking about the HTTP request method. The reason I created a dictionary object and printed it out was to see if the aiohttp.ClientSession() object's .get() method's return values would be greedily assigned to each dict value (meaning to say that a returned value would not be tied to any one loop iteration, and they would be assigned on a first-come, first-served basis, so you might get results like '1=1, 2=2, 3=4, 4=5, 5=3').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. With quite a bit of modification, you can get async requests in a `gather` by creating a set of `tasks` like this:

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio


async def main():

    res_dict = {}

    # list of urls
    urls = []
    for number in range(1,20):
        pokemon_url = f'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{number}'
        urls.append(pokemon_url)

    # list of tasks (with the gather)
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(get_pokies(url)) for url in urls]
    responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    # make the dict
    for i, response in enumerate(responses):
        res_dict[i] = response['id']
        
    print(res_dict)


async def get_pokies(url):
    ''' async func for the reqest '''
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.json()


asyncio.run(main())
```

This will be **much faster** than the original code in the question, since now the requests are made "in parallel" as opposed to "in series"...

Comment: Hey, @D.L,  thanks for not just answering my question, but for also teaching me an even better way of doing things! If I could give you two likes, I would. I'd love to hear if you have any books/courses to recommend, but if you don't, that's totally understandable! I wouldn't want to take up too much of your precious time :)

Comment: i actually wrote a book on python coding:   which is here (https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0BHL2XKCR).  But more importantly, your question was an interesting one and i was actually quite surprised with the gain (so i will certainly use the techniques myself).

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks :)
Delivery of that book to where I live (I live on the other side of the world) would kill me, so I'm trying to buy the kindle version if it's not too rude of me. :) 


But now, I'm faced with yet another issue... aiohttp.ClientSession() with no .create_task and .gather() will still perform much better than a query with no await at all (by a factor of 2 or 3 at least). I'll post that question elsewhere LOL. It's so perplexing.

Comment: My guess is that the usual 'await' method without '.gather()' and '.create_task' actually already batches the tasks into batches of 2-3, and that is why it is 2-3 times faster than a blocking method, and yet slower than doing everything in 1 batch like .gather() does.

Comment: Ahh, never mind... I think I understand now, I think I see the reason for it. Your method created numerous aiohttp.ClientSession() objects, while the other one without 'gather' created just one aiohttp.ClientSession() object, and that poor object awaited multiple requests all on its own.

Comment: yes, that is correct.  And in fact that is the gain, from this parallelism.

Comment: Well... I can't purchase the Kindle book because of geographic/licensing issues. Do consider allowing your book to be licensed/sold globally if it does not cost you extra money (not sure if Amazon charges you extra for that)! :)